Unable to detect release of mouse button when drawing shapes on geographical map using Folium-Draw
Upon clicking on the drawing shapes in the drawing tab provided by Folium-Draw, it is unable to detect the release of the mouse button which signals the completion of drawing but instead, it continues to draw another shape and this process is repeated till the Escape key is pressed.
When this happens, the shape boundary coordinates are also not captured in the [all_drawings] fields at all.
Please advise. Thanks
We have downloaded and tested the sample Draw project available on Gitlab. However, with the exact same codes, when we port in over to our offline environment, the mouse release button issue appears again
